# Leaflet + EPSG:31466 WMS layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, wms

I want to  create a Leaflet map using the **EPSG:31466** projection. I've included the `proj4` library as well as the `proj4leaflet` plugin. I'm planing to include [this](http://xplanung.lkee.de/xplan-wms-neu/services/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities) WMS service using the `fp_plan` layer.

I've tried to to set up my map using the following approach ([fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGMdNr?editors=0010)).

```
// Define CRS (EPSG:31466)
var rs31466 = new L.Proj.CRS(
  'EPSG:31466',
  '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=6 +k=1 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs',
  {
    origin: [
      2490547.1867, 
      5958700.0208
    ],
    resolutions: [
      10000000 * 0.00028, //GroundResolutionInMeter * OGC_PixelWidth
      5000000 * 0.00028,
      2500000 * 0.00028,
      1000000 * 0.00028,
      500000 * 0.00028, 
      250000 * 0.00028,
      100000 * 0.00028,
      50000 * 0.00028
    ]
  }
);

// Create the WMS layer
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://xplanung.lkee.de/xplan-wms-neu/services/wms', {
    version: '1.3.0',
    crs: rs31466,
    layers: 'fp_plan',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: false,
    // The `continuousWorld` property should be set to make sure Leaflet doesn't 
    // try to wrap or cut off the tiles on Spherical Mercator's bounds.
    continuousWorld: true
});

// Define the map
var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: rs31466,
  center:[51.310, 13.393],
  zoom: 1,
  layers: [
    wmsLayer
  ]
});
```

I would have expected to see something like this:

[image: Expected result]

The tiles are requested but the section does not contain the expected layer information. If I use the **EPSG:25833** projection the tiles are fetched and rendered exactly in the expected manner ([fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJXxrw)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've whipped out [an example](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/hom/edit?html,output) changing the origin of the tile coordinates and adding a rectangle to check the general geographical coordinates.

It does request tiles, and it seems to me like the coordinates of the BBOXes of the requests are fine, but I can only see white tiles.

Maybe that example can help you see what's wrong?

**[edit]**

It seemed that Leaflet doesn't respect the coordinate order (northing-easting or easting-northing) for WMS 1.3 request on custom CRSs. I think this is a leaflet bug.

In the meantime, I [updated the example](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/fex/edit?html,output) with a hacked `L.TileLayer.WMS.getTileUrl` function - and now it seems to load OK.

Comment: BTW, I've created an upstream bug at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4253