# leaflet and WMS version >= 1.3.0

Tags: leaflet, projection, wms

I'm using lealflet to represent some layers obtained from a WMS server over OSM.
The WMS version is 1.3.0 and I have to project coordinates from EPSG:6706 to EPSG:4326

I know that passing from version 1.1.1 to 1.3.0 there are two changes in the GetMap request:

1. SRS -->CRS
2. the order of the BBOX coordinates goes from "longMin,latMin,longMax,latMax" to "latMin,longMin,latMax,longMax"

Leaflet has no problem with point no.1 while does not change the boundind box representation.
I spent some time looking for a parameter or something like in openlayer (axisOrientation: 'neu') but I did not found anything moreover I tried setting bbox in the options with no success.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: I expect you to have read and understood the Leaflet WMS/TMS tutorial. Because you've read it, right?

Comment: I read It, maybe I have misunderstood something and that's the reason why i'm looking for help. I know I have omitted to write that I'm using also proj4leaflet but I don't know if that was your suggestion

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337356/leaflet-epsg31466-wms-layer/35417637#35417637 , then